# Adding different classed through looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of `li` elements, and I need to a class to the 1st, 4th and 7th, the 2nd,  5th and 8th, and the 3rd, 6th and 9th.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it...

```
var classes = ["first_group", "second_group", "third_group"];

$("li").addClass(function(i) {
    return classes[i % 3];
});​
​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynz3J/).

Comment: Tnx alex : . If you don't mind could you pls explain this line 'return classes[i % 3];'

Comment: @aneeshraj modulus operator. It returns the remainder of a division. By dividing each index by `3` and getting the remainder, we will get a number between `0` and `2`, which coincide with indexes of our array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
$("li:nth-child(3n+1)").addClass("one");
$("li:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("two");
$("li:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass("three");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vDTWn/

Comment: visioN .tnx.. but getting one syntax error. could you pls check

Comment: @aneeshraj It should work fine. Check that you correctly used the code.

Comment: @VisioN: Your answer contains the dreaded jsFiddle invisible character. It's right after the last `;`.

Comment: I assume you pasted your code into your answer from jsFiddle. Anyway, wherever it came from, you have an invisible character at that position that causes a SyntaxError in some browsers. If you edit your answer, put the cursor past the last `;` *(make sure you go far enough to the right)*, then press your left arrow key a couple times, you'll notice that it pauses for one key press. That's where the character is.

Comment: @user1689607 That's wow. The first time I face with this in SO. Thanks!